# When adding into an object using a 'count' variable, var 'count' still is 0

Tags: javascript, object, for-loop, count

I'm working through a coding exercise and stumped with this function. The function I'm trying to create is to take in a string, record number of repetitions for each word. The issue is when I'm trying to add into the object using myObject.key = value, when passing the var count, the count that is being put into myObject is still 0, **even though** it is being updated.

```js
function countWords(string) {
  var myArray = string.split(" ");
  var myObject = {};

  for (var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {
    var currentWord = myArray[i];
    //var count2 = 0;
    var count = 0;
    
    for (var j=i+1; j<myArray.length; j++) {
      var nextWord = myArray[j];
      console.log(currentWord + ' and a ' + nextWord)
      console.log('countBefore: '+count)
      if (currentWord===nextWord) {
        count += 1;
      }
      console.log('countAfter: '+count)
    }//for loop2
    
    console.log('countOutside: '+count)
    myObject[currentWord] = count;
  }// for loop
  
  return myObject;
}

//console.log(countWords('blah blah the the the he she be'));
console.log(countWords('blah blah the the the she'));
```

Some of the print statements probably are unnecessary but it may be helpful to understand so I left it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that each word is overwriting the count of any of the same word before it. So, you either need to remove each word after it is counted, or only change the value of count at a particular word if the new value is higher.

```
function countWords(string) {
  var myArray = string.split(" ");
  var myObject = {};

  for (var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {
    var currentWord = myArray[i];
    //var count2 = 0;
    var count = 0;

    for (var j=i+1; j<myArray.length; j++) {
      var nextWord = myArray[j];
      if (currentWord===nextWord) {
        count += 1;
      }
    }
    if (!myObject[currentWord] ||count > myObject[currentWord]){
      myObject[currentWord] = count;
    }
  }// for loop

  return myObject;
}

//console.log(countWords('blah blah the the the he she be'));
console.log(countWords('blah blah the the the she'));
```

You could probably make this more efficient by not bothering to count a word if you've already got a value for it (since you'll definitely get a smaller count on a later instance)

Comment: Thanks for the quick and concise response, could you expand on the if statement that you added. If not 0, or if count is greater than previous recorded count, add to myObject?

Comment: The `!myObject[currentWord] ` is to handle if we haven't defined that index yet. If you haven't, store the value. If you have, only store it if it's higher. Would probably work fine with just the `!myObject[currentWord] ` though.

Answer (score 0):

`for (var j=i+1; j<myArray.length; j++) {` the entire issue is caused by j=i+1 as this will cause the objects' value to be set to 0 due to the fact that finalCount will become 0 unless `currentWord` and `nextWord` evaulates to true.

From what I understand of your function name, you want to take a string and find out how many instances of each word there is.

Here's a cleaned up working fiddle with some comments:
https://jsfiddle.net/gzqm5k0d/